# What exactly is the "size" parameter in QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

The **size** parameter is used in many functions in quickcheck. But I am having difficulty understanding what it is exactly. What does [getSize](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html) return?

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Erjmh/QuickCheck/manual.html):

> Test data generators have an implicit *size* parameter; `quickCheck` begins by generating small test cases, and gradually increases the size as testing progresses. Different test data generators interpret the size parameter in different ways: some ignore it, while the list generator, for example, interprets it as an upper bound on the length of generated lists. You are free to use it as you wish to control your own test data generators.
>
> You can obtain the value of the size parameter using
>
> ```
> sized :: (Int -> Gen a) -> Gen a
> ```
>
> `sized g` calls `g`, passing it the current size as a parameter. For example, to generate natural numbers in the range 0 to size, use
>
> ```
> sized $ \n -> choose (0, n)
> ```
>
> The purpose of size control is to ensure that test cases are large enough to reveal errors, while remaining small enough to test fast.

And `getSize` is just another way to get that size parameter. Note that `getSize` is equivalent to `sized pure`, and `sized` is equivalent to `(getSize >>=)`.

Comment: If I write a generator for a customized data type, what is its `size`? I have to define it?

Comment: @sinoTrinity What data type exactly? Can you edit it into your question?

Comment: I'm not asking for a specific data type, but a generic one.

Comment: In `arbitrary`, `size` isn't a value you set; it's a value you get. For fixed-size types like `Maybe`, you ignore it. For variable-sized types like `List`, you make the list have `size` elements.

Comment: Yes, I can read/get it, I can also set it w/ `resize`. But what's its initial value and where is it set in the first place? Is the value different for different `arbitrary`s?

Comment: bump. How to create a custom generator for which you can set a size?

Comment: @TheCodingWombat You can use [`resize`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:resize) for that, but first double-check that you actually have a good reason for a generator to do so.